# Joomla disable parent template?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I am building a Facebook canvas app, and the code suppose to be generated in Joomla component.
I need to only output the content , excluding the default layout. 
any ideas?

Comment: Well I want component to display just a the content when refered via url, usually site uses template which has widgets right? and it displays those widgets along with content that is generated in component

Comment: I know that I can add menu item and set to this manu item some empty layout and point it to the component I need - but I don't need this menu item to show up, Of course I we can make this menuItem hidden through tricks, but it is just wrong(I know that 90% of joomla is all wrong but still adding tricks and wrong things will lead to mess). As I suppose if Joomla makes good use of hooks, then it should be possible to switch layout somewhere in plugin depending weather the URL is looking for - "myFacebookCanvasComponent", any thoughts ?

Comment: of course better would be disable layout, instead of switching to empty one =)

Comment: anybody? or will have to look at Joomla Code (it is usually the best way but takes time)

Comment: I suppose that here people don't really tolerate the Joomla =), well after looking at the architecture and code I also think it is bad. But sometimes we have to do what we have to do, can't tell the client to switch some other things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view called view.facebook.php (instead of view.html.php), it will be called when index2.php?.....&view=facebook will be attached to URL.

or you can call die() just after you execute your code, but do I need to explain that it's not ellegant?

Answer (score 9):

To display only the contents of the view on the page without being framed by a template, the tmpl variable needs to be set to “component”.

```
JRequest::setVar('tmpl', 'component');
```

To learn more,See [this](http://www.rvdavid.net/joomla-how-to-hide-the-administrator-or-front-end-layout-template/).